# MediaElement.js Audio only player: How can I get it to display the player at a certain width?

Tags: parameters, mediaelement.js

for instance, I use the  tag with a src set and it plays fine.  However, mediaelement creates a container that is set to 400x by 30px.  If I use  this has no effect.

If it matters I am using this as part of the HTML5 Media embed plugin for Wordpress, but I am using the audio tag manually and that is calling mediaelement.js.

Answer (score 4):

```
$('audio').mediaelementplayer({
    audioWidth: 500,
    audioHeight: 500
});
```

will do the trick!

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem working with media element. However, if you need the audio player to be bigger than 30px, which it looks like you do, then you can just set a min-height.

```
.mejs-container { min-height: 80px }
```

If you need it smaller, do the same with a max-height.

```
.mejs-container { max-height: 20px }
```

This is how I got around it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how the wordpress plugin works but you can set the audio width/height in the mediaelement options when you initialize it. See the player options at the mediaelementjs site